# trigger.io facebook authorize "unexpected failure" with iphone 5

Tags: iphone, facebook, trigger.io, forge

I have an app which requires a Facebook login.  The logic call uses

```
forge.facebook.authorize(
    [''], 
    function() { ... }, 
    function(content) { alert(JSON.stringify(content)); } 
);
```

This call works fine on Android and ios 5 and 6 on iphone 4 and ipad.  It also used to work for iphone 5.  However, recently my iphone 5 gives the error,

```
{
    "message": "The operation couldn't be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error)"
    "type": "The operation couldn't be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error)"
    "subtype": null
}
```

I'm using Forge tools version 3.3.28 and platform version 1.4.

This is preventing iphone 5 users from accessing the app.  Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem wasn't iphone 5.  In my phone's "Facebook" settings, the setting for "Allow These Apps to Use Your Account" were set to "off" for my app.  Oops.